# Get string entry from textfile in php

Tags: php, file, fwrite, fread

I have a question. How can i get a string from a entry in a textfile.

The texfile looks like:

```
Blabla2|123456
Blablablabla4|475387638
Blab1|387549900
```

Now i want to get from Blablablabla4 the number behind the |

Whats the read file function for it?

Comment: try `fgetcsv()` and use `|` as delimiter.

Comment: Have you tried something ? *Whats the read file function for it?* Have you asked your **best friend google**? (You know you can ask your best friend google everything :)

Comment: Ive googled of course, but i didnt know the keywords to find such thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom function, if you need that value often with different keys.

```
function getValueFromFile($file, $key){
    if (($handle = fopen($file, "r")) !== FALSE) {
      while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, "|")) !== FALSE) {
        if($data[0] == $key){
            fclose($handle);
            return $data[1];
        }
      }
      fclose($handle);
    }
    return false;
}
```

and simply call it like:

```
echo getValueFromFile("your file name", "Blablablabla4");
```

Answer (score 1):

Load each line of file to `$line` and then use function `explode('|', $line_variable)` for separating a string from int.

```
$handle = fopen("inputfile.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        $line = explode('|', $line);
        $string = $line[0];
    }

    fclose($handle);
 } else {
    // error opening the file.
```

}